# Variable width of absolute div contained within fixed-width div

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have a `<div> display:table` setup, which has a "help" icon in a fixed width column. When I hover over the icon, the tooltip appears allowing the user to hover the mouse over the tooltip as well (which could contain hyperlinks).

The problem is that the tooltip is displaying based on the width of the fixed cell, meaning the contents are word-wrapped based on only having the 20px width of the cell.  The tooltip is **variable length and potentially multiple line**.

This is what I have so far...

```css
.table {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
.row {
  display:table-row;
}
.cell {
  display:table-cell;
  border:1px solid #888;
  padding:5px;
}
.tooltip {
  position:relative;
  width:20px;
}
.tooltip > div::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-30px;
  height:20px;
  width:30px;
  background-color:transparent;
}
.tooltip > div {
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  top: 0px;
  left: 30px;
  border: solid 1px #a0a0a0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.tooltip:hover > div {
  display:block;
}
.tooltip > div p {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<p>Hover over the X to show the tooltip... you should be able to move the mouse over the tooltip, and the tooltip should disappear when the mouse moves out of the tooltip or the X...</p>
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell tooltip">
      <i>X</i>
      <div>
        <p>
          Hello world hello world
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      This is a whole load of other text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Without** using a fixed width for the tooltip, how can I make the popup variable width, and still be able to "exit" the tooltip by moving the mouse to the right?

Here is the same example with an extra nested `<div>` and a fixed width of `500px`, which means the variable content is displayed correctly. But you'll see the tooltip does not disappear when the mouse is moved to the right, because it's still hovering over the fixed 500px width container...

(Note, I've put a background colour on the fixed width container to highlight the "hover" area)

```css
.table {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
.row {
  display:table-row;
}
.cell {
  display:table-cell;
  border:1px solid #888;
  padding:5px;
}
.tooltip {
  position:relative;
  width:20px;
}
.tooltip > div::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-30px;
  height:20px;
  width:30px;
  background-color:transparent;
}
.tooltip > div {
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  top: 0px;
  left: 30px;
  width:500px;
  /* NOTE, Added to highlight the fixed container area */
  background-color:rgba(127,127,255,0.4);
}
.tooltip:hover > div {
  display:block;
}
.tooltip > div > div {
  display:inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #a0a0a0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.tooltip > div > div p {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<p>Hover over the X to show the tooltip... you should be able to move the mouse over the tooltip, and the tooltip should disappear when the mouse moves out of the tooltip or the X...</p>
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell tooltip">
      <i>X</i>
      <div>
        <div> <!-- Note, extra nested div -->
          <p>
            Hello world hello world
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      This is a whole load of other text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to get the variable length tooltip to display without needing a fixed width `<div>`?

---

**Note,** I've added an answer that uses jQuery, but I would prefer CSS-only solution if anybody knows of one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I would have preferred a CSS-only result, I've come up with a solution that requires javascript (or in my case jQuery) so that it automatically changes the width based on the content at point of display...

```js
$(function() {
  $(".tooltip").on("mouseenter", function(e) {
    // Get the inner <div> container
    var $div = $(this).children("div");
    // If we haven't already worked it out
    if (!$div.data("widthset")) {
      // Set the width of the container to width of the contents, and set as worked out
      $div.css("width", $div.children("div").outerWidth(true) + "px").data("widthset", true);
    }
  });
});
```

Here you can see it in action...

```js
$(function() {
      $(".tooltip").on("mouseenter", function(e) {
        // Get the inner <div> container
        var $div = $(this).children("div");
        // If we haven't already worked it out
        if (!$div.data("widthset")) {
          // Set the width of the container to width of the contents, and set as worked out
          $div.css("width", $div.children("div").outerWidth(true) + "px").data("widthset", true);
          console.log($div.css("width"));
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
.table {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
.row {
  display:table-row;
}
.cell {
  display:table-cell;
  border:1px solid #888;
  padding:5px;
}
.tooltip {
  position:relative;
  width:20px;
}
.tooltip > div::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-30px;
  height:20px;
  width:30px;
  background-color:transparent;
}
.tooltip > div {
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  top: 0px;
  left: 30px;
  width:500px;
  /* NOTE, Added to highlight the fixed container area */
  background-color:rgba(127,127,255,0.4);
}
.tooltip:hover > div {
  display:block;
}
.tooltip > div > div {
  display:inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #a0a0a0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.tooltip > div > div p {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hover over the X to show the tooltip... you should be able to move the mouse over the tooltip, and the tooltip should disappear when the mouse moves out of the tooltip or the X...</p>
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell tooltip">
      <i>X</i>
      <div>
        <div> <!-- Note, extra nested div -->
          <p>
            Hello world hello world
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      This is a whole load of other text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell tooltip">
      <i>X</i>
      <div>
        <div> <!-- Note, extra nested div -->
          <p>
            Lots and lots of tooltip text, which is really long and should in theory, if I keep typing long enough, cause the line to extend over the 500px onto the next line
          </p>
          <p>
            And also include a new paragaph as well
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      And this is a whole load more text to give another example row, and show via the console that the width is only worked out once
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```